# query to select common fields from dynamic list of tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that I created in MySQL of 1 minute stock prices.  The database is setup so each stock has its own table named by its symbol containing Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume.  Also there is a table called symbols that has Symbol, Type.  The ultimate goal of the database is to be able to get prices for a range of dates from a collection of symbols.

this query works for selecting a subset of symbols from the symbols table:

```
SELECT symbol 
FROM minute.symbols 
WHERE type = 'ETFs';
```

this query works for selecting a subset of dates from a single stock:

```
SELECT 'SPY', date, close 
FROM minute.SPY 
WHERE date > '2000-01-04 09:30:00' AND date <= '2000-01-04 10:00:00';
```

this query works for selecting common prices from two stocks:

```
(SELECT 'SPY', date, close 
 FROM minute.SPY 
 WHERE date > '2000-01-04 09:30:00' AND date <= '2000-01-04 10:00:00'
) 
UNION 
(SELECT 'QQQQ', date, close 
 FROM minute.QQQQ 
 WHERE date > '2000-01-04 09:30:00' AND date <= '2000-01-04 10:00:00'
)
```

i'd like to be able to combine query #1 and query #2 into one query to get results like query #3, but for all tables returned by query #1.

is this feasable and efficient or should i instead dynamically build query #3 which may result in 100s of UNIONS?

Comment: What you call "creating a matrix" is more commonly called pivoting.  It's hard in SQL and usually done in a client programming language, like PHP, Ruby or ASP.NET

Comment: While it'd be nice to do the 'pivot' in SQL, i guess i can do that in the program that calls the query.  So i guess i really want to figure out how i can have query #2 run on the tables returned from query #1.  Also i guess if i need to do the pivoting outside of SQL i need to add a symbol name field to each symbol table or is there someway to avoid that?

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't include all prices in a single table with an extra "stock" column to split them up?  This would be a heck of a lot easier if each stock didn't have its own table!

Comment: yeah i tried that originally, the problem was that populating the table was really slow. table pimary key was (date,symbol). first stock took 1 min to upload, 10th stock took 10 mins because of indexing. there are around 250 stocks typically with over 1m rows each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this by using Stored Procedure.

- You would pass type and the date ranges as parameters.
- You would run a cursor over the first table (symbols)
- Loop over the cursor and build the SQL string with help of Concat
- In the end when you have the query built, you make is of Prepare and Execute to run it